# Script to calculate task duration for Cloud Composer (Airflow tasks) using stackdriver logs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm new to using Composer service of GCP and wanted to calculate the time duration for which my each tasks run. Is there any script that I can run to get the duration of each tasks of Airflow DAG's from Stackdriver logs.  I'm able to manually calculate the duration by subtracting the start and end time of tasks but I want to do it using a script. Please can anyone help me here. I'm attaching the screenshots of the logs getting generated for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can examine Airflow metrics in Monitoring for workflows (DAGs) and the Celery Executor. To help you monitor the efficiency of your workflow runs the following workflow metrics are available:

1. Number of workflow runs: `composer.googleapis.com/workflow/run_count`
2. Duration of each workflow run: `composer.googleapis.com/workflow/run_duration`
3. Number of task runs: `composer.googleapis.com/workflow/task/run_count`
4. Duration of each task: `composer.googleapis.com/workflow/task/run_duration`

As you can see, please use `composer.googleapis.com/workflow/task/run_duration` API.
Cloud Monitoring shows only the metrics for completed workflow and task runs (success or failure). Additionally, have a look for the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/monitoring-environments#workflows).